# In TensorFlow, how can I selectively apply a function only to the maximum elements of each row of a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 2D tensor, and I want to apply a function only to the maximum elements of each row.  For example, if my tensor is:

```
[[0.5, 0.7],
 [0.4, 0.3]]
```

and my function is to multiply by 2, then I want my result to be

```
[[0.5, 1.4],
 [0.8, 0.3]].
```

My current approach is to use `tf.select`, like this:

```
tf.select(tf.equal(my_tensor,
                   tf.reduce_max(my_tensor,axis=1)), 
          my_function(my_tensor),
          my_tensor)
```

The idea is to create a tensor which is the max of each row using tf.reduce_max, and then use tf.equal to create a boolean tensor which says whether each element of input is equal to its row max.  This then gets passed to tf.select as a mask to determine whether the function should be applied.  However, this doesn't seem to work - the max tensor is not of the same dimension as the input tensor, and I think there's some issue with broadcasting.  Also, this method may run into issues if there are two equal maximal elements.  I'd rather have a method that automatically breaks ties, perhaps using tf.arg_max.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to modify the code in the question by using tf.expand_dims on the result of tf.reduce_max to get a tensor of the proper shape to be broadcast to match the input tensor.  The result looks like this:

```
tf.select(tf.equal(my_tensor,
                   tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_max(my_tensor,axis=1), axis=1)),
          my_function(my_tensor),
          my_tensor)
```

While this works, I suspect there is a cleaner method.